# Deploying Postgresql Along Windows Application

Tags: c#, postgresql, deployment, setup-deployment

I have WPF application which using Postgresql as Database engine. I want to install Postgresql  engine  and restore/attach application-Db to it.

The application's users are non-technical people and they can not install Postgresql individually.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> The application's users are non-technical people and they can not install Postgresql individually.

then try this , silently install PostgreSQL, we are using the similar code in our software deployment

```
C:\Installer\postgresql-9.0.2-1-windows.exe  --serverport 5432 --servicename postgres_service --locale C --superaccount Myadmin --superpassword Mypassword --unattendedmodeui minimal --debuglevel 2 --mode unattended
```

run this as the bat file , install in the background

> 1. **postgresql-9.0.2-1-windows.exe**

This is your exe

> 1. **serverport 5432**

This is your port number where you want to install Postgres

> 1. **superaccount Myadmin**

You use account name

> 1. **superpassword Mypassword**

Your user password

keep the rest same.
This will directly install to `c:\Program Files`

Comment: Thank you, it worked for me too,just one thing: If i want to install silent postgresql and after that, initdb, create a role and a database and load a backup in the database or script, is possible to do that in a batch file?

Answer (score 2):

I presume you want to deploy on Windows, so you can include PostgrSQL in your application installer, you can create an application installer for example with [InnoSetup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php) ...

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://www.enterprisedb.com/edb-docs/d/postgresql/installation-getting-started/installation-guide-installers/10/PostgreSQL_Installation_Guide.1.16.html#) are the details of Postgresql silent install on Windows. Installers can downloaded from [here](https://www.enterprisedb.com/downloads/postgres-postgresql-downloads). Once it's installed then you can run your db script off-course.

Comment: Many thanks, the link you provide doesn't include msi files, can you provide link to download msi files>

Comment: @Behnam download from here whatever version you want http://www.postgresql.org/ftp/odbc/versions/msi/